# How do programs know the types at runtimes of primitives statically typed languages

Tags: scala, reflection, go, types

Both Go and Scala provide ways of checking types at runtime:

Scala:

```
class A
class B extends A

val a: A = new A // static type: A dynamic type: A
val ab: A = new B // static type: A dynamic type: B
val b: B = new B // static type: B dynamic type: B

def thing(x: Any): String = x match {
    case t: Int => "Int"
    case t: A => "A"
    case t: B => "B"
    case t: String => "String"
    case _ => "unknown type"
}
```

Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

struct A {
    field1 int
    field2 string
}

func printTypeOf(t interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(t))
}

func main() {
    i := 234234 // int
    s := "hello world" // string
    p := &A{3234234, "stuff"} // *A

    fmt.Print("The type of i is: ")
    printTypeOf(i)
    fmt.Print("The type of s is: ")
    printTypeOf(s)
    fmt.Print("The type of p is: ") // pass a pointer
    printTypeOf(p)
    fmt.Print("The type of the reference of p is: ") // pass a value
    printTypeOf(*p)
}
```

How exactly does this work internally? I presume for structs and classes, the type of the object is stored in a hidden field (so the structure in golang is really struct { field1 int field2 string type type }. But how on earth can function be given 11010110 and know whether it's a pointer to memory address at 214, the integer 214 or the character Ö? Are all values secretly passed with a byte which represents its type?

Comment: Your presumption is incorrect, there are no hidden fields in a Go struct. All types are known to the compiler at compile time.

Comment: Go, in simple terms: when you call `printTypeOf(x)`, x is wrapped in an interface value. This value has the "hidden field" you were thinking about.

Comment: Given that it is wrapped, that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, each object has a pointer to its class. When you call `thing` with a primitive argument (`Int`, `Char`, etc.), it's automatically boxed to an object (`java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Character`, etc.). The match against `Int` in your code is actually translated to a match against `Integer`.

In Go, the type isn't stored in structs, but in interface values:

> [Interface values are represented as a two-word pair giving a pointer to information about the type stored in the interface and a pointer to the associated data. Assigning b to an interface value of type Stringer sets both words of the interface value.](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)

So when you call `printTypeOf(whatever)`, `whatever` is converted to `interface {}` and its type is stored in this new value along with `whatever` itself.

Comment: Ok I can see how that works for interface{} types in Go and objects in Scala. Just use the correct offset and get the type information. But if I pass a plain old integer represented by the byte 11010110, how does it know that I meant it as an integer, rather than a pointer or a character and to box it with a pointer to the integer type.

Comment: In other words, how does Scala box 11010110 to an Integer class with a value field of 214 rather than a Character class with value Ö?

Comment: "But if I pass a plain old integer represented by the byte 11010110, how does it know that I meant it as an integer" By its static type. If that's `Int`, it's boxed to `Integer`, if `Char` to `Character`, etc. And if `Any`, it's already boxed.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense since in my scala example, ab get's matched on it's static type rather than dynamic type. But isn't the static type only known at compile time, whilst these reflection feature work in the runtime?

Comment: No, it is matching on runtime type. My point is that if you have a "plain old integer", it's static (and runtime) type is _always_ `Int`. So the compiler knows how to box it.

Comment: Ah so the boxing is done by the compiler. So when you give an integer to a function, the compiler inserts a conversion to a interface{} type or Integer type. That makes sense, thanks.